# can stat_poly_eq() be added to plotly plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

One can easily include `stat_poly_eq()` in `ggplot`, but is there any way to include this on a `plotly` plot?

When I tried using `ggplotly`, it does not render `stat_poly_eq()`.

Or should I use a different function in the case of `plotly`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change a ggplot including `stat_poly_eq` with ggplotly. The new plotly object still got the polynomial regression.

Working example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
library(plotly)
set.seed(4321)
x <- 1:100
y <- (x + x^2 + x^3) + rnorm(length(x), mean = 0, sd = mean(x^3) / 4)
my.data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y,
                      group = c("A", "B"),
                      y2 = y * c(0.5,2),
                      w = sqrt(x))

# give a name to a formula
formula <- y ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)

# no weights
p<-ggplot(my.data, aes(x, y)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = formula) +
   stat_poly_eq(formula = formula, parse = TRUE)

ggplotly(p)
```

[image: Plot]

Only difference is, that you don't get your textbox of `R^2`. There is nothing we can do about it, since it's not implemented yet (11.2020) as the error message shows.

---

If this still does not work for you. You can just include a regression by hand and add it to `plotly`. This is taken from an existing solution. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49491570/9783433) for giving credits. This way it's easier to modify and you can add all the information you need.

```
  library(plotly)
  library(dplyr)
  data(cars, package = "datasets")

 qfit1 <- lm(dist ~ poly(speed,2), data = cars)

  cars %>%     
  plot_ly() %>%  
  add_lines(x = ~speed, y = fitted(qfit1)) %>%
  add_trace(x=~speed, y=~dist)
```

Adding a text for your R squared could be:

```
  add_annotations(text= sprintf("R^2: %f", summary(qfit1)[8]), showarrow=FALSE, xref="paper", yref="paper", x=0.05,y=0.9)
```

For more options and customization check the documentation off add_annotaions.

[image: [plot2]]

Comment: I need to have R^2 value on the plot. It is possible in ggplot but not in plotly or ggplotly

Comment: @kolas0202 when you calculate it with `lm` you can add R^2 with a text field. That's why I concluded the second solution.

Comment: @kolas0202 I inserted the R^2 value with an example